# Salvar o estado do Fragmento?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Num app simples eu tenho **Fragments e preciso salvar o estado deles**,

para que quando o usuário retorne de um fragmento para o outro,

**ainda esteja lá o texto digitado, numero escolhido, check box marcada, etc...** sugestões ?

Answer (score 1):

1. No fragmento, salva o estado `overriding onSaveInstanceState()` e guarda em `onActivityCreated()`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's state here
    }
}

...
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    //Save the fragment's state here
}
```

2. Na atividade, tens de guardar o instance do fragmento no `onSaveInstanceState()` e guarda-lo no `onCreate()`.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        //Restore the fragment's instance
        mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    //Save the fragment's instance
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
}
```

Espero que isto ajude.

Queria comentar, porque a respsta ja foi dada no SO ingles, mas como nao consegui, escrevi aqui e traduzi.Espero que isto ajude.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313598/once-for-all-how-to-correctly-save-instance-state-of-fragments-in-back-stack

O codigo não esta a ficar em código, se alguem souber por, agradecia!!

Comment: Não é bem isso, mas obrigado.