# Salvar a instancia de um fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

A `MainActivity` chama o fragment ao ser iniciado.

Tenho tabs que alternam pelos fragments. Traço uma rota em um dos fragments e ao sair, clicando na tab e ao voltar, a rota some, gostaria que ela ficasse instanciada ainda.

Gostaria, por um bundle talvez, que ao voltar de um outra tab, eu possa continuar com a rota traçada na tela.

Se alguém puder me ajudar nesta questao.
[Salvar o estado do Fragmento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137486/salvar-o-estado-do-fragmento-no-android)

Tentei implementar algo como na resposta acima mas nao deu certo.

Comment: Como está a fazer a alternância entre TAB's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha só, você pode usar o próprio ciclo de vida do `fragment` como o `onActivityCreated`. Geralmente esse tipo de situação de perder os dados e ter que recuperar acontece, por exemplo, quando é rotacionado a tela. Neste seu caso, para gravar uma rota, você basicamente precisa de um `array` de coordenadas certo?! Então vamos lá,  veja o código abaixo e adapte-o as suas necessidades:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    private List<String> myData;

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("list", (Serializable) myData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            myData = (List<String>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("list");
        } else {
            if (myData != null) {

            } else {

                myData = computeData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

De uma observada nestes gifs referente ao momento onde ele salva e o momento de restauração de um `Fragment`:

#### Salvando e Restaurando estado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Encontrei este *[artigo](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en)* e achei bem interessante. Vale a pena ler.